# Use for-loops to output a triangle of *'s

Tags: java, for-loop

I want to output a triangle of *' s like so:

```
*
**
***
```

This is my code:

```
public class triangleStars {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

                for(int N=0 ; N<=3 ; N=N+1)
                {
                    for(int M=0 ; M!=N ; M=M+1)
                    { 
                        System.out.println("*");

                    }
                    System.out.println();       

                    }
            }

    }
```

If I run the code I get stars under each other and a line in between and adding a star after every line. What am I missing?

Comment: Use `print` instead of `println` in the inner loop.

Comment: To add some context to Andy's comment, `println` prints the stirng you give it (optional) and then a newline. `print` just prints the string with no newline appended.

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: I've got one more question regarding this though. I want to implement an int N so that if i change N the amount of rows change. for example in this code I would have N=3. How would i implement this?

Comment: You probably want to post a new question for that - posts containing more than one question usually don't fit the Q&A format well.

Answer (score 0):

Change println of inner loop to print

Answer (score 0):

Use `print` instead of `println` in the inner loop.

`println` prints the string you give it (optional) and then a newline. `print` just prints the string with no newline appended.

Answer (score -1):

This might work for you!

```
public class TriangleStars
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int M, N;
        for(M=0; M<5; M++)
        {
            for(N=0; N<=M; N++)
            {
                System.out.print("* ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

}